# Arguments of setkeyentity of keystore

Tags: java, security, cryptography, password-protection

I am using keystore to protect the private key in a file using the following code

```
ks.setKeyEntry("kk1", pr, pass, cert1);//ks is obj of keystore,
                                       //kk1 is alias,
                                       //pr-->is private key,
                                       //pass->is the password to protect that key,
                                       //cert1-->is the certificate chain..
```

Later i want to store it in the file,uisng store function.
My problem is

```
  (actual argument java.security.cert.X509Certificate cannot be converted to java.security.cert.Certificate[] by method invocation conversion)
```

I have given cert1 as

```
 X509V3Create obj=new   X509V3Create();  //it is my own class
 X509Certificate cert1  = obj.generateV3Certificate(pair);
 //in this method I set all the certificate parameters like version,alg etc..,pair is obj of key pair...
```

I am getting the error which I mentioned above..I can't set that parameter to null(it gives null pointer exception)

What should I pass as argument???

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
java.security.cert.Certificate[] certificateChain = new java.security.cert.Certificate[]{cert1}
ks.setKeyEntry("kk1", pr, pass, certificateChain);
```

Comment: No,it is not working..Error is-->incompatible types
  required: java.security.Certificate
  found:    java.security.cert.X509Certificate

Comment: You are importing the deprecated java.security.Certificate somewhere. Change that to java.security.cert.Certificate or be explicit about using java.security.cert.Certificate (as in the modified answer).